# can we initialize value using ng-init from controller that value get from server side(php) to controller in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

index.html:

```
<form name="cca">
 <input type="text" ng-model="form.product_id"  ng-init="form.product_id=prod_id">
 <input type="button" ng-click="profile_updated()">
  </form>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.profile_data_init = function() {    $scope.prod_id="hi";    }    //its working fine
```

but i can't init value get from server side using controller..code below

```
 $scope.profile_data_init = function() {

   //alert('uu');
    //console.log($scope.loginform);
    $http.post("ajax/profile_updation.php",{profile_up_init:"profile_init"}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.prod_id=data[0].pid; //json data
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         alert("Please Try Again..!");
     });
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure response is in success ..??Check it by console.log(data[0].pid)

Comment: ya sure..but it doesn't show value while dynamically get from server side through controller using angularjs..if i give static without any post using $http.post  to server ,it works..i can't identify..why..what is wrong with my code..

Answer (score 0):

Try your request in `ng-init`

```
<form name="cca">
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.product_id"  ng-init="profile_data_init()">
    <input type="button" ng-click="profile_updated()">
</form>
```

and set `$scope.form.product_id = $scope.prod_id = data[0].pid;` on success

```
$scope.profile_data_init = function() {
    $http.post("ajax/profile_updation.php",{profile_up_init:"profile_init"}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.form.product_id = $scope.prod_id = data[0].pid; //json data
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Please Try Again..!");
    });
}
```

Comment: then init this object in your controller e.g. `$scope.form = {};`